# How to insert script in AMP WordPress

Tags: functions, scripts

I'm helping a company with their WordPress website, and it is running AMP. They want to add a script, so i have tried inserting it in functions.php, header.php, and footer.php but it doesn't show on in Chrome Inspector.
How would i do this?
I've tried this in functions.php:

````
function my_footerscripts(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(e,t,o,n,p,r,i){e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias=n;e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias]=e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias]||function(){(e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias].q=e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias].q||[]).push(arguments)};e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias].l=(new Date).getTime();r=t.createElement("script");r.src=o;r.async=true;i=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];i.parentNode.insertBefore(r,i)})(window,document,"https://diffuser-cdn.app-us1.com/diffuser/diffuser.js","vgo");
    vgo('setAccount', 'XXXXXTHEIR_IDXXXXX');
    vgo('setTrackByDefault', true);

    vgo('process');
</script>
<?php
}; ```
````

Comment: [Google Analytics's AMP page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/) says "AMP does not allow any JavaScript beyond its own approved libraries" so unless your tracker has a custom AMP tag like Google do you might be out of luck.

Comment: As to how to actually add things to AMP output, that likely depends on which AMP plugin you're using. You probably want their documentation or support team in the first instance.

Comment: Wow, crazy that it has to be in their own library. I have found the author of the AMP plugin, and have written to them. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The whole point of AMP is to limit the ability to add arbitrary scripts, so it's not very surprising.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, i have come to realize. I haven't worked with AMP before.